# Move an object (element) one step up with Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, filter, javascript-objects, extjs4.1

I have several objects like this:

[image]

I want to move `type` and `value` one step up so they will be next to `field`, and then delete `data`.
It looks like this when `departments` is converted to JSON:

```
[
    {"field"    : "DEPARTMAN_NO",
     "data"     : { "type":"numeric" , "comparison":"eq" , "value":11 }
    },
    {"field"    : "DEPARTMAN_ADI",
     "data"     : { "type":"string" , "value":"bir" }
    }
]
```

I have tried:

```
departments = grid.filters.getFilterData();
i = {};
for(var i in department) {
department = i.data;
delete.department.data;
};
```

but it dosen't work.

Comment: Can you post markup/code? I can't see your picture on my intranet?

Comment: @ElRonnoco, I wonder what you use.

Comment: @ElRonnoco, I have updated for you.

Comment: The reason your `delete` doesn't work is because you need to say `delete obj[property]` where `property` is the property to delete. Also you don't declare `i` properly - you should remove `i = {}`. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) First, loop `departments`, each item we call it `department`;
2) You want to move `department.data`'s properties to `department`, From another angle, you can move `department`'s properties to `department.data` and return `department.data`, code like:

```
var departments = [{
        "field": "DEPARTMAN_NO",
        "data": {
            "type": "numeric",
            "comparison": "eq",
            "value": 11
        }
    }, {
        "field": "DEPARTMAN_ADI",
        "data": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "bir"
        }
    }],
    department;

for (var i = 0, len = departments.length; i < len; i++) {
    department = departments[i]; // department
    for (var key in department) {
        if (key !== 'data' && department.data) {
            department.data[key] = department[key];
        }
    }
    departments[i] = department.data || department; // if no department.data, no change
}

console.log(departments);
```

result:

[image]

view the full demo http://jsfiddle.net/KVYE5/

Comment: i was going to answer just the way up here. but wiky faster so +1 :)

Comment: However there are several `obj `s within `departments`

Comment: On the demo code, `obj` is an item of `departments`, and you just need to loop the 'departments', others are same.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little npm package that does what you're asking for: moving a property up a level in an object.

You can get it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/move-property-up-a-level

## Usage

```
var movePropertyUpALevel = require('movePropertyUpALevel');

var fakeObj = {
    poodle: {
        first: {
            hey: 'you'
        },
        second: 'meAgain'
    }
};

movePropertyUpALevel(fakeObj, 'poodle');

console.log(fakeObj.first.hey);
//'you'
console.log(fakeObj.poodle);
//undefined
```

Comment: "Useage" is misspelled.

Answer (score 1):

```
obj =
[
    {"field"    : "DEPARTMAN_NO",
     "data"     : { "type":"numeric" , "comparison":"eq" , "value":11 }
    },
    {"field"    : "DEPARTMAN_ADI",
     "data"     : { "type":"string" , "value":"bir" }
    }
];


for ( var item in obj ) {
    if ( obj[item].field && obj[item].data ) { //check the 'field' and 'data' exist
        obj[item].field = {
            dept : obj[item].field ,         //department name is put into a property
            type : obj[item].data.type,      //so is data.type and data.value..
            value: obj[item].data.value      //..all are now contained in 'field'
        };
        delete obj[item].data;               //remove the 'data' object
    }
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
department.type = department.data.type;
department.value = department.data.value;
delete department['data'];
```

Comment: I think I have to loop because it says that `department.data.type`
 is undefined.

Comment: Is `departement.data` defined? Can you give us a greater view of your object tree ?

Comment: I think the Java Script engine doesn't understand what object I'm referring to because there are 2 objects within `departement`. So it might be more appropriate to write something like `departement.[0].data`.

Comment: Maybe. That's a valid syntax. It's hard to say if it's appropriate without knowing the whole object tree.

Comment: `departement.data` is not defined. I have updated the question.