# Accessing object within object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {{
    data: {
        type: 'string',
        value: 'bir'
    },
    field: 'red'
    },
    {
    data: {
        type: 'string',
        value: 'bir'
    },
    field: 'green'
    }
};
```

How do you manipulate the `data`s.

Comment: You have invalid object declaration. The most external object should have keys.

Comment: As bjornd says, that code is invalid. You either need to assign keys to each of the internal objects or use an array of objects.

Comment: is this the same as your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/11258908/697154

Answer (score 1):

As an objects array it could be valid :

```
var obj = [{
    data: {
        type: 'string',
        value: 'bir'
    },
    field: 'red'
    },
    {
    data: {
        type: 'string',
        value: 'bir'
    },
    field: 'green'
    }
];
```

But then again some context would be welcome ^^